# Strange Hiring Procedure

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, applications

I received a phone call about a certain job I applied to.

It was the assistant who had a preliminary short interview.

Later on, she said she is going to contact me by means of e-mail, to let me know when her manager is going to phone-interview me by phone.

The next day, the manager calls me half an hour prior to the time agreed for the interview, and he tells me he had to defer the interview.

I didn't receive any phone call yet (today).

Is this hiring process peculiar?

Comment: sounds about right for IT.

Comment: What strikes you as peculiar?  The fact that the company had to postpone a phone screen isn't terribly unusual-- life and production issues comes up and sometimes schedules need to be juggled.  You don't say whether they deferred the phone screen to earlier today, in which case the comment about not receiving a phone call would be more problematic.

Comment: Could be that they're passing on you. I would wait 3 (business) days and if you hear nothing then send a email. If you still hear nothing, then move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to the point where the manager called early to defer the interview that process sounded normal. Needing to defer the interview is a little bit odd but emergencies happen.

The part where they haven't called back yet (assuming they set a date & time for another call when the manager called to defer) is a bit odd. My best guess is they've either passed on you (like [Dan](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/40426/dan) said) or weren't organized enough to call back when they told you they would. By all means contact them in another day or two, but contact them only once and don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not peculiar. Remember, there's a whole world of activity on the other side of the process to which you are not privy.

Here is a small sample off the top of my head of things that could have happened:

1. There's been a change in the position, either in the position itself (no longer hiring for it) or the description.
2. Something could have happened with the recruiter, such as a change in job status (promotion, termination, etc)
3. There could be new positions that you may be a better fit for and/or pays them more money so they're more motivated to fill
4. The recruiter called you by mistake, meaning to call someone else (i.e. made the wrong note on your resume). This actually happened to me once.
5. There could be internal changes in management or process that causes them to adjust their focus.
6. They lost the client.
7. The manager overruled (or recruiter changed mind) and decided you're no longer a fit.

These are just simple ones off the top of my head. I assure you that there could be many, many reasons.  In other words, **a delay doesn't in itself mean anything**.

Give it a couple of days and send an email to the recruiter.  Give it a few more and send an email to the manager if you haven't heard back.

They may also just be simply busy.

Comment: Or the manager had a personal emergency and the reason why they didn't set a time right then was because they don't know when he will be available again.

Comment: Exactly my point. It could literally be anything.